# Symfony forms - Expected argument of type "string", "DateTime" given

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I get this error message:

> "Expected argument of type "string", "DateTime" given"

This is the code of my form in symfony

```
$builder->add('dateOfBirth', 'datetime', [
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'label'  => 'Geboortedatum',
    'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control birthdaypicker'],
    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']
]);
```

And this is the template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form_pupil.dateOfBirth) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form_pupil.dateOfBirth) }}
        <small>{{ form_errors(form_pupil.dateOfBirth) }}</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Document (Entity)

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Date
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Een geboortedatum is vereist")
 * @Assert\Length(max=10, maxMessage="Een geboortedatum kan maximaal 10 karakters bevatten")
 */
 protected $dateOfBirth;
```

In my document(entity) it's also a date type. I have no idea why Symfony expects a string..

Comment: Can you post more details about the error message? Is it coming from Symfony form/validation or from Doctrine ODM?

Comment: vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/LengthValidator.php at line 33   -
        }
        if (!is_scalar($value) && !(is_object($value) && method_exists($value, '__toString'))) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($value, 'string');
        }
        $stringValue = (string) $value;

Comment: In case anyone hits this error, I came across when I had an invalid validation rule in a validation.yml config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Assert\Length(max=10, maxMessage="Een geboortedatum kan maximaal 10 karakters bevatten")
```

Can't check the length of a datetime object! (removed this assert and it worked)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$builder->add('dateOfBirth', 'datetime', [
    'data' => new \DateTime(),
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'label'  => 'Geboortedatum',
    'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control birthdaypicker'],
    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']
]);
```

Comment: Can't use \DateTime(), Mongo doesn't support datetime and i only need date.

Comment: if you replace `datetime` by `date` removing `'data' => new \DateTime(),` line it works ?

Comment: I changed the second parameter of add to date. And removed the 'data' in the third parameter array.

But the main problem was the assert validation in my Document. I used @Assert\Length on a date object. Which caused the error.

Comment: why do not you do the check to the creation of form?